# How much longer is the site going to be in beta for?

Tags: discussion

I don't know why I care, I'm just a bit curious

Comment: Here's a blog post largely covering this issue: **[When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)**

Comment: And as long as we're looking at stats: **[Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)**

Answer (score 14):

It's not something directly in our control, it's entirely up to the Stack Exchange team to make that call.

[Our stats are building up well towards various targets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589?phase=beta), so if we keep sharing, asking and answering, I don't think it'll really take too long, hopefully within another few months if things go well.

[image]

Comment: Projecting some of those stats out, I'd say another 3 months. Maybe less, if we get a bit of network effect - we are picking up google juice every day.

Comment: The main stat is users - so as mentioned in the past : if its worth an answer - its worth a vote up - keep voting

Comment: @metadaddy that is a long 3 months!

Comment: @Reaper - yeah, isn't it just. I'll chase down the current status after Thanksgiving. Need to decompress after DF13!

Comment: @metadaddy looking forward to an update!

Comment: OK - so, the update is, the redesign of Salesforce StackExchange was waiting on StackExchange redesigning the nav bar (the strip at the top of the page), which [went live today](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/). Salesforce StackExchange has moved to the front burner now, so, hopefully, we'll see something in the next few weeks!

Comment: Sweet action! That new navbar just confused the hell out of me when I logged in :+)

Comment: thanks for the update @metadaddy

Answer (score 8):

Latest StackExchange podcast looks promising :)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/podcast-49-the-one-where-we-edited-out-the-title-reference/

> (...) In graduation news, Salesforce is going to fully graduate after
>   a very quick run through the beta process. (...)

Comment: Hooray! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Do you ever sleep? :) Good catch `☺`

Comment: What do you mean @mastor, I've posted it on 9:30 PM local time, it's not that late ;)

Comment: Interesting that 4 months later, it's still "beta"...

Answer (score 7):

Out of curiosity, I asked on Area 51 about the timeframe, and I received a response from someone who works for Stack Exchange.

The good news is that they're working directly with Salesforce on the branding of this site. However, it may take a while, yet.

> We don't have a set duration for betas; sites "graduate" (I think what you mean by launching - getting a custom site theme and whatnot) whenever the our community managers' periodic evaluations deem them ready and our designers have time to create the design. We are actually currently working directly with Salesforce on an initial design to propose to the community. Because we're working with SF, and we're also going to be rolling out a new network-wide top bar design that will impact future site designs, this process is moving slower than normal, but we're moving towards it.
>
> I'm not going to venture a guess at a timeframe because I'm not closely involved in this project, but keep an eye out on Salesforce.SE's meta site for announcements from community managers or designers in the coming weeks and months. Until then, there is nothing functionally incomplete about our beta sites; the biggest change that comes with graduation is cosmetic (the custom theme). – Laura

So, they're still working on it; we just need to keep checking back here on the progress in the next few weeks/months.

Comment: Great news, can't wait to check out a new design!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Area 51 we are so close to graduating

**we have 141 / 150 users with 200+ rep ( Lets upvote some good answers and close this gap )**

Need to improve on :
1.8 - 2.5 answers per question ( Depends on the question being asked)
15 questions per day on average ( we are at 14.4 nothing much to do here since this totally dependent on the user traffic)
14.4/ 15 asked per day - Unless there is more exposure this would be hard to increase

WE NEED MORE :O trafficccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

Comment: The good news is that traffic growth does not appear to be slowing down. I embedded a [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/salesforce.stackexchange.com) graph in [this answer](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/299/154).